# Avoiding jerk when changing hidden to auto overflow property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a modal dialog to be opened. When the modal window is opened i want to disable background scroll. So i have added `overflow:hidden` to the `body` tag when the dialog is opened. By doing this scroll bar comes and goes for the `body` tag, Which in result causing some jerk to my UI. I understand this jerk will happen because of the reserved space used by the scroll bar. Is there is any way to avoid the jerk and also to disable the background scroll when the dialog opened and closed.

Please find the code attached below

```js
var launch =  document.getElementById('btn');
var dialog =  document.getElementById('dialog');
var close = document.getElementById('close');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
launch.onclick = openModal;
close.onclick = closeModal;

function openModal(){
 dialog.style.display = "block";
  body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closeModal(){
 dialog.style.display = "none";
  body.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.overall{
  height:1000px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  text-align:right;
  padding: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
  
}
.modal{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:#aaa;
  border:1px solid #fdfdfd;
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
}
span{
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
  text-align:right;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="overall" id="btn">
   click to launch modal
</div>
<div class="modal" id="dialog" style="display:none">
  <span id="close"> close</span>
</div>
```

Closely note `click to launch text` it will have a jerk due to the above mentioned issue

Please refer the working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/santhoshkumar14/wp0rw5c5/)

Comment: Why dont you use bootstrap modal it will help you rather wriitng lot of css and you have to write those controls which already exist in bootstrap UI

Comment: I usually wont believe in third parties. Like to write code myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could temporarily add a `margin-right` that's the width of the scrollbar. If you have lots of styling and background colors going on, it might not be sufficient. But for simple layouts it works fine.

```js
var launch =  document.getElementById('btn');
var dialog =  document.getElementById('dialog');
var close = document.getElementById('close');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
launch.onclick = openModal;
close.onclick = closeModal;


function openModal(){
  var widthBefore = body.offsetWidth;
  dialog.style.display = "block";
  body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  
  body.style.marginRight = body.offsetWidth - widthBefore + "px";

}

function closeModal(){
  dialog.style.display = "none";
  body.style.overflow = "auto";
  body.style.marginRight = "";
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.overall{
  height:1000px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  text-align:right;
  padding: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
  
}
.modal{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:#aaa;
  border:1px solid #fdfdfd;
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
}
span{
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
  text-align:right;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="overall" id="btn">
   click to launch modal
</div>
<div class="modal" id="dialog" style="display:none">
  <span id="close"> close</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @degr If you look at the code, you see I calculate the scrollbar size dynamically. It's not a fixed value.

Comment: Yes, I see, but still not good idea, because margin can be already used in some custom CSS style.

Comment: @degr I covered that with the disclaimer at the start of the answer. It's up to the OP to decide if this works for their site, but I think it's fair to say that it *does* work for the example that was provided in the question.

Comment: whats this line does... body.offsetWidth - widthBefore. It returns zero according to ur code

Comment: When I store the width in `widthBefore`, there's still a scrollbar. Then, you set the `overflow` to `hidden`, making the scrollbar disappear and the offsetWidth change. This line calculates the difference between those two situations, to be able to correct for the width change caused by the removal of the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is only one way how to resolve your issue:
1. keep overflow as is:

```
function openModal(){
    dialog.style.display = "block";
}
```

2. set position to fixed:

   .modal{
         position:fixed;
    }

Answer (score 0):

As a solution - you can reserve this body space after hiding scrolls using body margin class. So when you hides vertical scroll - you are increasing body right margin, when you shows - remove this reservation.

Check example below. It has some disadvantages (different browsers, different OS themes, etc), but it was quick fix for my project.

So additional calculation may be required, like current scroll width. http://jsfiddle.net/UU9kg/17/

```js
var launch =  document.getElementById('btn');
var dialog =  document.getElementById('dialog');
var close = document.getElementById('close');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
launch.onclick = openModal;
close.onclick = closeModal;

function openModal(){
 dialog.style.display = "block";
  body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  body.style.marginRight = "17px";
}

function closeModal(){
 dialog.style.display = "none";
  body.style.overflow = "auto";
   body.style.marginRight = "0";
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.overall{
  height:1000px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  text-align:right;
  padding: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
  
}
.modal{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:#aaa;
  border:1px solid #fdfdfd;
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
}
span{
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
  text-align:right;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="overall" id="btn">
   click to launch modal
</div>
<div class="modal" id="dialog" style="display:none">
  <span id="close"> close</span>
</div>
```

Comment: scrollbar width is browser dependent.

Comment: Yes, it is. And OS theme dependent. But it was solution in my particular case, so I just shared very quick fix.

Comment: I have updated my answer. As your default state is scroll on you can get scroll width before hiding to get correct value http://jsfiddle.net/UU9kg/17/

Answer (score -1):

Add a `overflow-y: scroll` to the `html` to force a scrollbar by default. This will prevent the centering jump when when the modal appears.

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This issue is also browser dependent as some browsers scrollbars don't take up horizontal space (like Chrome).